# how can I use same data source for Kendo chart and kendo multi select?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-chart, angular-kendo, kendo-multiselect

I am using kendo angular chart and multiselect. Right now I am call same api twice to load the data in both. Is there any way to define multiple schema in same api call? My data is like following

```
{
  "List": [
    {
      "Name": "xyz",
      "Activation": "2016-12-08",      
      "End": "2016-12-09",
      "Run": "45",
      "Status": "FAILURE",
      "color": "red"
    },
    {
      "Name": "wqe",
      "Activation": "2016-12-07",        
      "End": "2016-12-08",
      "Run": "46",
      "Status": "FAILURE",  
      "color": "red"
    }
  ],
  "NameList": [
    {
      "Name": "joo"
    },
    {
      "Name": "foo"
    },
    {
      "Name": "too"
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to add "List" in grid  and "NameList" to be added in multi select in one api call.

currently I am using following code to call api

```
function getDataSource(requestUrl) {

    var dataSource = {
        transport: {
            read: requestUrl,
            dataType: "json"
        },
        schema: {
            data: "List",
            total: function (response) {
                return response.StatisticList.length;
            },
            model: {
                fields: {
                    Name: { type: "string" },
                    Activation: { type: "date" },
                    End: { type: "date" },
                    Run: { type: "number" },
                    Status: { type: "string" },                        
                    color: { type: "string" }
                }
            }
        },
        sort: { field: "ActivationTime", dir: "desc" },
        pageSize: common.Grid.pageSize
    };
    return dataSource;
}

function getMultiSelectDataSource(requestUrl) {

    var dataSource = {
        transport: {
            read: requestUrl,
            dataType: "json"
        },
        schema: {
            data: "NameList",
            model: {
                fields: {
                    Name1: { type: "string" }
                }

            }
        }
    };
    return dataSource;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to achieve data binding of both widgets with one request in your scenario, if you make the request manually yourself, and use [local (custom) transport](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/datasource/crud#local-or-custom-transport-crud-operations) or static [`dataSource.data`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#configuration-data) assignment in the DataSources of the Chart and MultiSelect.