# Is it possible create multiple schema and modal in Kendo data source?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, angular-kendo, kendo-multiselect

I am remotely binding kendo grid and kendo multiselect with separate api call. So I was wondering if I can make single call and create multiple schema in order to fill both widget.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how can I use same data source for Kendo chart and kendo multi select?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41069319/how-can-i-use-same-data-source-for-kendo-chart-and-kendo-multi-select)

Comment: Its possible if I only have one key in Json...I want to assign two differnt key to grid and multiselect @dimodi